# Binding to a collection of child ViewModels in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a domain model that looks like this:

```
* Parent
  * ParentProperty1
  * ParentProperty2
  * Children (an array of Child objects)
* Child
  * ChildProperty1
  * ChildProperty2
```

I have a created a custom `ChildUserControl` that binds to a child via a `ChildViewModel`. My main window is bound to a `ParentViewModel` and contains a `WrapPanel` that displays one `ChildUserControl` for each child owned by that parent.

The XAML for the panel is:

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <editor:ChildUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

The problem with this is that it sets the `DataContext` of each `ChildUserControl` to a raw `Child` object, rather than wrapping them in `ChildViewModels` first. Is there some way to tell XAML to create a view-model for each child object during the binding process? Or does my `ParentViewModel` need to explicitly expose a bindable collection of `ChildViewModels`? Thanks.

Comment: `Or does my ParentViewModel need to explicitly expose a bindable collection of ChildViewModels`: this is the more common way, but IMO you're already doing that when binding to `Children`

Comment: @Stefan Currently, `Children` is a collection of `Child` objects, not `ChildViewModel` objects. It seems odd to have a view-model that contains child view-models, but maybe that's the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does my ParentViewModel need to explicitly expose a bindable collection of ChildViewModels?

It should.

> Is there some way to tell XAML to create a view-model for each child object during the binding process?

No, the XAML processor cannot create a view model for each child that wraps the actual child element. XAML is a *markup* language.

You could possibly use a [value converter](https://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html) that binds to the child object and returns a child view model object:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <local:ModelToViewModelConverter x:Key="converter" />
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <editor:ChildUserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

But I would certainly prefer to expose the appropriate types from the ParentViewModel.